# Java Swing update TextField without any action

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield

I created an app in netbeans using swing where i have several `JTextFields` that i want to update in a cycle without using a buttonactionclick... the problem is when i put in the code of netbeans `jFieldText1.setText("test");` in `main` or in a function... it doesn't appear in the gui... is there any way to do this without having to press a button to update the results?

what i want to do is keep polling using a cycle that updates the `JTextField`.

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `it doesn't appear in the gui.`

I hope above is for the text you want to see in your `jtextfield1`

What you need to do is put your code to change the text in `JTextField` in some Java Swing event.
You can refer this document about Java Swing [`EventsListeners`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) and [`ActionListeners`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

There is a method of `JButton` by which you can click the button on some Event or Action which is `button.doClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `add(jFieldText1)` to actually add it to the `JFrame`. Make sure you actually have a `JFrame`, too.

Comment: i have it in a JFrame since im using netbeans to make the GUI... it just doesnt update unless i put the code in the button action

Answer (score 0):

//Global Declaration

```
JTextField jTextField;
```

//Add TextField to frame

```
jTextField=new JTextField(20);//OR you can do it here also  jTextField=new JTextField("Text");
add(jTextField);
```

//Now you can set text to TextField

```
jTextField.setText("Text");
```